# How to variable from another module.exports file permanently

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create an API call to change a variable (in this case, a password) in another file (config.js) and I want to change the value of "mainpassword" permanently (or at least until i want to change it again), without having to do complicated fs.readFile and write bullshit.

Setting `config.mainpassword = "somethingelse"` does not modify the variable in the config.js file

**index.js**

```js
//...expressjs and other stuff here
const config = require('./config.js');

app.post('/api/admin/changesitepassword', (req, res) => {
    config.mainpassword = "fumo123"
    const conffile = require('./config.js')
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./config.js')];
    return res.send(`Changed password: ${config.mainpassword}\nconfig.js: ${conffile.mainpassword}`)
})
```

**config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    //... other config info

    mainpassword: 'fumo', // Password to lock behind

    //... other config info
}
```

and when I POST to it,

```
Changed password: fumo123
config.js: fumo
```

and it doesn't change

Comment: Self-modifying code is rather terrifying. And how would you even commit this to version control? Just use a configuration file (e.g. in JSON format) and write the "complicated fs.readFile and write bullshit" (which is about five lines, probably less).

Comment: Well, what I meant by the readfile stuff, was having to scan through the lines, checking if the line includes the password field, store that line into a variable, change the part where the password is, then do some other complicated code to save the file.

But you do prove a point with JSON

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is save your config in a `.json` file whenever it changes, and load it up when you start your application.

This will not watch the file for changes, so if you change the password manually in the file you will have to restart the server.

```json
{ "mainpassword": "fumo123" }
```

```js
// config.js
const fs = require('fs') // some minimal amount of "bullshit" is required
const config = require('./config.json')
config.set = (key, value, callback) => {
  config[key] = value
  fs.writeFile('./config.json', JSON.stringify(config), 'utf-8', callback)
}

module.exports = config
```

and then you can use your `set` method to set and save the changes

```js
app.post('/api/admin/changesitepassword', (req, res, next) => {
    // i'm assuming express is used here, so I pass the error to `next`
    config.set('mainpassword', "fumo321", err => {
        if (err) return next(err)
        return res.send(`Changed password: ${config.mainpassword}`)
    })
})
```

the password is now dynamicaly updated for every places that import the config